# Jenkins: Calling a GLOBAL library from a FOLDER library

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a global library, which is normally loaded thusly:

```
@Library('pipelineUtilities')
def utils = new com.booty.jenkins.libraries.pipelineUtilities()
```

I have a folder library (in the `vars` directory), which looks like this:

```
#!groovy
class vars {
    public static String gitAuthorization = "Basic TEzZmVGMH...lZMTNmZUYwZWU="
}
```

I hate hardcoding stuff like that, so I want to use a `util` function called `getBasicAuth()`

```
public String getBasicAuth(String account, String password){
    String userPass = account + ":" + password
    String basicAuth = "Basic "+ userPass.getBytes().encodeBase64()
    return basicAuth
}
```

When I try to just use the @Library without actually using a library

```
#!groovy
@Library('pipelineUtilities')
class vars {
    public static String gitAuthorization = "Basic TEzZmVGMH...lZMTNmZUYwZWU="
}
```

there is no problem, but nothing interesting really happens, of course, we just processed the `@library` annotation.

However:

```
#!groovy
@Library('pipelineUtilities')
def utils = new com.booty.jenkins.libraries.pipelineUtilities()

class vars {
    private String serviceAccount = "xxxxyyyy"
    private String serviceAccountPassword = "yyyyzzzzzz"
    public String gitAuthorization = utils.getBasicAuth(serviceAccount, serviceAccountPassword)
}
```

does not pass the `def utils = new com.....` step, let alone call `utils.getBasicAuth()`. What it does is crash in some mysterious way.

So - 2 questions:

1. how do I put a `try/catch` block inside my code so i can see what went wrong in the `@library` section
2. How do I call a global library from within a folder library...

Alas, it is all so counter intuitive :-(

Thanks, .a.